# MYSQL | Can't create a new thread (errno 12); if you are not out of available memory

Tags: mysql, database

i have installed mysql executable on local machine on windows 7.

Database is working fine, but sometimes it gets very very slow, and today i got this error.

```
Can't create a new thread (errno 12); if you are not out of available memory, you can consult the manual for a possible OS-dependent bug
```

i ran simple query..

```
select * from `hrms_test_db`.`ml_month` limit 0, 1000
```

system is Core 2 Duo, and 4GB Ram..

How can i make my mysql server run smoothly? 5 friends are accessing the server altogether for development purposes..

[**my.ini**](http://pastebin.com/thYNQG3A) from below path

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini
```

also link if above link not working. 
http://pastebin.com/thYNQG3A

+-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-=

**Update:**
[image]

Comment: I guess you should check that connections are properly closed in all scripts/programs.

Comment: I agree with @Alexander. If it gets slow with only 5 users, its highly likley a simple miss somewhere of closing connections. You allow `max_connections` = 3000, this seems very high, lower this to `100`. Maybe its using up all the connections (i think each conenction allocate 1mb/connection)

Comment: @KayNelson
Sorry, I dont know much about databases, i just tried to change the configuration numbers to get better performance, instead i guess i made it worse..
When i restart the mysql, it works good, but when time passes, it start getting slower and slower.. :(

Comment: @KayNelson
What does max_connections do??
Does Max Connections means how many queries can a mysql run at one time or how many users can connect to server at once??
cuz we only 5 persons do connect to the server at once..

Comment: it just tells how many connections mysql allows to have open at the same time. If it becomes slower faster now, that indicates even more you forgetting to close connections at some point in your application. If you execute `show processlist` in mysql , what does the result say?

Comment: MySQL opens a connection whenever mysql_connect() is called and it closes the connection whenever mysql_close() is called. So, for every mysql_connect that is executed before the queries, you need one mysql_close that is executed after the queries. Otherwise, you get an orphaned connection that will eventually time out, but counts towards the maximum until then.

Comment: @KayNelson
i did `show processlist` it showed list of 11 items.. updating image in my question..